# Converting column names to row values based on conditional flags

Tags: r, automation, dplyr, medical

I am working with health care data which has different body parts and radiology tests as columns. Below is a snapshot of the data frame -

```
 loc_brain  loc_bone  loc_pelvis  mod_ct  mod_xray
   0          1          1          0        1
   1          1          0          1        0
   0          0          1          1        1
```

1. All the columns starting with "loc" flag the body parts. Similarly, columns starting with  "mod"  flag the radiology tests
2. The idea is to create two new columns called location and modality which should follow the below output pattern

   ```
   loc_brain  loc_bone  loc_pelvis  mod_ct  mod_xray  location            modality
     0          1          1          0        1      bone pelvis         xray
     1          1          1          1        1      brain bone pelvis   ct xray
     0          0          1          1        1      pelvis              ct xray
   ```

If the "loc" columns are flagged 1, then the new location column will have the name of the body parts. Same applies to "mod" columns.

The way I was approaching this problem was using dplyr and looking at each combination flags and filling the location and modality values.

```
input_df$location<-""  
input_df$modality<-""  
input_df <- input_df %>%  
            mutate(location= replace(location,(loc_bone==1 & loc_pelvis==1),"bone pelvis")) %>%  
            mutate(modality= replace(modality,mod_xray==1, "xray"))
```

1. There are about million rows and 65 columns of body parts and tests.
2. Finding all the combination and mutating each combination is messy. Is there a way to automate this approach either using dplyr or base R?

Below is a reproducible example of the input data frame -

```
loc_brain<-c(0,1,0)  
loc_bone<-c(1,1,0)  
loc_pelvis<-c(1,0,1)
mod_ct<-c(0,1,1)  
mod_xray<-c(1,0,1)  
input_df<-as.data.frame(cbind(loc_brain,loc_bone,loc_pelvis,mod_ct,mod_xray))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input_df)[, loc := paste0(gsub('loc_','',names(.SD)[.SD==1]), collapse = ' '), 1:nrow(input_df), .SDcols = 1:3
                ][, mod := paste0(gsub('mod_','',names(.SD)[.SD==1]), collapse = ' '), 1:nrow(input_df), .SDcols = 4:5][]
```

which gives:

```
   loc_brain loc_bone loc_pelvis mod_ct mod_xray         loc     mod
1:         0        1          1      0        1 bone pelvis    xray
2:         1        1          0      1        0  brain bone      ct
3:         0        0          1      1        1      pelvis ct xray
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that works, although I'm not sure how generalisable it will be.

First get the column references of the "location" columns, and use that to extract just the "location" values ("bone", "brian", etc.).

```
location.columns <- grep( "^loc_", names(df) )

location.values <- names( df )[ location.columns ]
location.values <- sub( "^loc_", "", location.values )
```

Then separate out the location columns from the main dataframe, and use it to create the new column. We use `collapse` in the `paste` function to stick the various matching words together:

```
locations.df <- df[ , location.columns ]
df$location <- sapply( seq_len( nrow( df ) ),
                       function(x) {
                           paste( location.values[ locations.df[x,] == 1 ], collapse = " " )
                       }
)
```

Repeat those steps for the "mod" values:

```
mod.columns <- grep( "^mod_", names(df) )

mod.values <- names( df )[ mod.columns ]
mod.values <- sub( "^mod_", "", mod.values )

mods.df <- df[ , mod.columns ]
df$mod <- sapply( seq_len( nrow( df ) ),
                       function(x) {
                           paste( mod.values[ mods.df[x,] == 1 ], collapse = " " )
                       }
)
```

Which gives:

```
> df
  loc_brain loc_bone loc_pelvis mod_ct mod_xray    location     mod
1         0        1          1      0        1 bone pelvis    xray
2         1        1          0      1        0  brain bone      ct
3         0        0          1      1        1      pelvis ct xray
```